# Ajax form validation without caching

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am building an inline code validation for a web form. With my current script, When a bad code is entered and it is being corrected (same length), POST data is not using the latest value. For example, I first enter "QFFE" and then correct it to "QFFF", but the latter is not stored in $_POST. See Firebug extract ("QFFF" passed but "QFFE" processed):

[image]

Here is the code (AJAX part):

```
var data = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
      resetErrors();
      var url = 'process.php';
      $.each($('form input, form select'), function(i, v) {
          if (v.type !== 'submit') {
              data[v.name] = v.value;
          }
      }); //end each
      console.log(data);
      $.ajax({
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data: data,
          cache: false,
          success: function(resp) {
              if (resp === true) {
                    //successful validation
                  alert("OK, processing with workflow...");
                  //    $('form').submit();
                    return false;
              } else {
                  $.each(resp, function(i, v) {
            console.log(i + " => " + v); // view in console for error messages
                      var msg = '<label class="error" for="'+i+'">'+v+'</label>';
                      $('input[name="' + i + '"], select[name="' + i + '"]').addClass('inputTxtError').after(msg);
                  });
                  var keys = Object.keys(resp);
                  $('input[name="'+keys[0]+'"]').focus();
                  console.log('QD: error val');
              }
              return false;
          },
          error: function() {
              console.log('there was a problem checking the fields');
          }
      });
      return false;
  });
});
function resetErrors() {
    $('form input, form select').removeClass('inputTxtError');
    $('label.error').remove();
}
```

And here my PHP script (process.php):

```
<?php
//List of accepted codes
$code_list = array("QWOLVE", "QFFF");

session_start();
if(isset($_POST)){
    if (empty($_POST['promo_code'])) {
        $_SESSION['errors']['promo_code'] = 'Please enter a promo code to access the beta site';
        }elseif(! in_array($_POST['promo_code'], $code_list)){
            $_SESSION['errors']['promo_code'] = $_POST['promo_code']." is not a valid code";
            unset($_POST); 
        }
        if(count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0){
        //This is for ajax requests:
            if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&  strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
                echo json_encode($_SESSION['errors']);
//                   header('Location: redirect.php');
                exit;
            }
            //This is when Javascript is turned off:
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $key => $value){
                echo "<li>" . $value . "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";exit;
        }else{
            //Form validation successful - process data here:
            echo json_encode(true);
        }
}
?>
```

How can I make sure that the process.php is always using the latest form data?

Comment: `then correct it to "QFFF"` Your js-code doesn't correct anything. It just shows errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you store errors in the the session, but since you don't seem to clear that session, the next time you call the POST method $_SESSION['errors'] will still have the previous error in it (QFFE), hence the output.

Comment: Thanks, putting a session_destroy() after line 23 seems to do the trick.